# Server 2012 Server Core powershell not installed

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

In server core, after a restart powershell was all of a sudden not installed, what do I do to reinstall it?

I do not have remote administration set up yet so I cannot use that to re-install it.

'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: Did you verify the binaries are gone? It could be as simple as your %PATH% variable missing/broken.

Comment: Yes, the binaries are gone. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\ was empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM.exe) tool to enable PowerShell:

`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellRoot`

...or if that's not enough:

`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell /all`

Comment: I did try that, where was no option to install Powershell and enabling remote management did not do anything to install it

Comment: Thanks. Although I had to append `/all` onto the end of the second command.

I accidentally removed a feature in 2012's server manager and had to use this to get back on my feet again. After that I followed this guide: http://telnet25.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/server-core-install-gui/

Comment: I get the error "DISM does not suport servicing Windows PE with the /Online option ???

Answer (score 2):

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellRoot
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell /all
```

Say "yes" for reboot.

```
powershell
Add-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Shell, Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra
Shutdown -r -t 0
```

In server 2012 R2 Use `Shutdown /r /t 0`