# How do I disable hyper-v from command prompt in server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012

In previous versions, I might be able to remove Hyper-V through ServerManagerCmd.exe but this was apparently deprecated in 2012 (it seems it doesn't even exist) or dism /Online /disable-feature /featurename:hyper-v but it's telling me that it can't provide this service to Windows PE.

How do I accomplish the same thing within Server 2012? Is there a way to access powershell from the menu below? I try going to Command Prompt there and typing `powershell` but nothing. When I type `sconfig` to attempt to install powershell, it says that script doesn't exist.

EDIT:
I'm trying to do this from the recovery command prompt when you start up in advanced startup. I cannot boot into the OS since enabling Hyper-V

I am constantly being returned to this screen pretty much no matter what I do (other than going to command prompt):

[image]

The difference is it says continue to Windows DataCenter instead of windows 8. I tried the suggestion here : [Server 2012 Server Core powershell not installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/431010/server-2012-server-core-powershell-not-installed)

but i get the error "DISM does not support servicing windows pe with the /online option"

Comment: That is not a duplicate. The other one is about removing the feature through the wizard or powershell. I am asking about command prompt (e.g. advanced startup/recovery, etc)

Comment: Umm, have you tried booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes. What's happening is the computer continues to boot into advanced boot options (the blue screen with options to restore, etc). No matter what I select, if I try to load the OS, it'll restart the computer. So for instance, if I set it to boot into safe mode, it'll restart the computer. If I choose to "continue to windows" it'll restart the computer. Everything just restarts and leads to the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem, but at least I got answer to the original question:

Most examples I've found on the web gave me this which didn't work:

`DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`

Unfortunately, this won't work for PE. So instead of using the /Online option, you have to point it to an image. Here is the command I used to get it to finally run

`DISM /Image:C:\ /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`

Unfortunately, I'm still stuck in the loop of being returned to this options screen no matter what I do. But I have that posted in a different thread.

Comment: Using Dism /Image:C:\ solved my problem. I have an Lenovo X395 with Ryzen 5 Pro 3500 CPU. After installing Hyper-V Hypervisor through the Windows Feature GUI, the notebook restarts to a black screen. I can press F8 to boot to Windows PE command prompt and use the Dism /Image to remove the Hypervisor feature. The next notebook restart brings me back to normal Windows 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this particular challenge and a search for the solution brought me here. However, this is the solution that worked great.

Open command line ( Run as Administrator )

Go to the base prompt ( **C:\** )

Type:

> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off  [Enter]

You should get a response **"This operation completed successfully"**

Restart the computer.

Your VMware should be able to run now with the machines as well.

I got this result on my Windows Server 2012R2